# Excel line break vs VBA line break?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing VBA codes to read spreadsheet contents and write to a TXT file.

Some of the cells has multi-line text.  They are displayed as multi-line in the spreadsheet.

However, when the VBA code read the cell and write to the TXT file, they appear on the same line.  This also happens when I copy the cell and past it into Notepad.

For example in spreadsheet, cell A1 appears as:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

But in TXT file, it appears as: `Text1Text2Text3`.

So I guess CHAR(10) in Excel is not equivalent to vbNewLine in VBA?  What do I need to do to get the line breaks into TXT file?  Thank you!

Comment: Try char(13) & char(10) instead of only char(10).

Comment: Please post the code you use to generate the text file with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `Replace(YourCellValue, vbLf, vbCrLf)` to get line breaks that works in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and resolved it by changing my column to word wrap. Please be gentle if this is a silly solution - this is my first answer on the forum. :-)